# Catch 404 JSON response instead of crashing

Tags: android, json, http, http-status-code-404

I've got a Android app which is written to response to a web query that replies with a JSON response. When the query is correctly formatted, it all works fine. However when the query is wrong, the code crashes and I get the following in the stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://******
```

I've put `*****` in place of the query I placed for privacy here.

If I put the same query in a browser I get the following response:

```
{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Missing authentication"}
```

My question is - why is my code throwing an error instead of seeing this as a valid JSON response that I could then parse?

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

try {



URL u = new URL(params[0]);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    // Read the stream              

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while ( is.read(b) != -1) {
            baos.write(b);
    }

    String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());

        return JSONResp;
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the status code of httpurlconnection object using below code:

```
 if(conn.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED)
            {
                //handle the accepted response
            }
            else
            {
                //handle the failed response
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `getErrorStream()` to read the error stream of your backend call

> Returns an input stream from the server in the case of an error such
>   as the requested file has not been found on the remote server. This
>   stream can be used to read the data the server will send back.

```
InputStream is = null;
if (responseCode == 200) {
  is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
} else {
  is = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead to get the json response form server:

```
 private InputStream is = null;
   private String jsonString = "";
   private JSONObject jsonObj = null;

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) { //url is your url

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                if (sb.length() != 0)
                    jsonString = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("_TAG", "Buffer Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("_TAG", "Parsing Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return jsonObj;
        }
```

now get the **statusCode** from returned jsonObj by above method.